# Finding critical points of $f(x) = \frac{\ln(x^2-1)}{x^2-x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

In sketching the function below, I'm having a hard time finding the critical points of $f'(x)$, mostly because of factoring. The function is

$$f(x) = \frac{\ln(x^2-1)}{x^2-x}$$

and it's derivative

$$f'(x) = \frac{2x(x^2-x)-(x^2-1)(2x-1)\ln(x^2-1)}{(x^2-1)(x^2-x)^2}$$

I cannot find a way to factor it and find the critical points. What may I be missing?

Thank you.

Comment: The derivative is $$\frac{2 x^2-\left(2 x^2+x-1\right) \log \left(x^2-1\right)}{(x-1)^2 x^2
   (x+1)}$$. I doubt you can find critical points with a closed formula.

Comment: i have found this formula $$-\frac{-2 x^2+2 x^2 \log \left(x^2-1\right)+x \log \left(x^2-1\right)-\log
   \left(x^2-1\right)}{(x-1)^2 x^2 (x+1)}$$

Comment: it is the same as yours!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes its the same, we agree on that. How would you equal that to zero to find the critical points?

Comment: To compute the stationary points boils down to solving $$\log(x^2-1)=\frac{2x^2}{2x^2+x-1}$$ that is best suited for numerical methods, rather than exact ones.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I'm starting to believe that, I cannot seem to calculate it algebraically.

Comment: solutions are $$-2.2979333487176754344$$ or $$1.85308848505542835608$$